# div fixed scroll

Tags: css

I understand how to make a div slide as you're scrolling down the page. However I'm having trouble doing so.

It works if I do this:
http://screensnapr.com/v/aLbYHE.png

But that's setting the position to "fixed", but I want it to stay as "absolute" because on absolute it'll stay within it's div like this: http://screensnapr.com/v/Z93gKl.png

But then that takes away the scrolling for some reason. Here's the CSS bit:

```
<div style="float:right;position:absolute;right:25px;padding-top:35px;" style="top: 0px;">
      <a href="_lib/forms/comment.php?id=<?php echo $article_id; ?>" class="-button silver" rel="facebox"><span class="-paper">Post Comment</span>
      </a>
 </div>
```

absolute = http://screensnapr.com/v/Z93gKl.png (How it's positioned is what I want, but I don't have fixed on it, so it's not scrolling with me)

fixed = http://screensnapr.com/v/aLbYHE.png (How it's positioned is what I don't want, but It is scrolling)

would you guys happen to know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `absolute` will defeat your "sliding" (assuming you're using `fixed` to do that).  `absolute` will put an element RIGHT THERE and it WON'T MOVE.

I'm assuming you're talking about the comment button.  Without seeing any code I can't help much, but what you could do is position it with `absolute` *inside* a parent element that moves in a `fixed` manner.

Comment: http://www.krissales.com/#/media/38.Testing-Another-One-Yo i actually got it working on the 14% position fixed. it works smoothly.  But it moves as soon as you scroll, is there a way to tell it to only scroll once you move below the post comment ?

Answer (score 0):

using `position:fixed` is what you want.

The problem you're running into is that the `right:25px` declaration now means '25px away from the right edge of the browser window'.

You'll need to update that 'right' value to 50%, and then use a property like `margin-left` and push the button into the right place.